# How to reference Java interface constants within EL

Tags: jsp, el

I need to reference some constants held in a java interface, (they were put there by previous developers). But the problem of course is you get the error message:

```
javax.el.ELException: The class [com.foo] must be public, non-abstract and not an interface
```

What is the best way to go about accessing these constants? I have a workaround where I implement the interface in a class file and reference the constant from there in my jsp file. But it seems a bit of a roundabout way of doing it. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Actually, the question is __not__ answered by the referred question. This question is specific for constants in interfaces. This cannot be solved with proposed solution of referred question.

Answer (score -2):

As a workaround, you could bypass EL and use a [JSP scriptlet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html) instead:

```
<%
jspContext.setAttribute("CONSTANT_NAME", InterfaceName.CONSTANT_NAME);
%>
```